# Using $routeProvider without specifying template and ng-view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to use angular's routing function only to bind views and controllers without indicating template and ng-view.

This is what I have so far, and is working well.

JavaScript

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/home', {
                    controller:"myCtrl", template:"whatever"
                })
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        }
    ])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModue'])
```

HTML

```
hello!
<div ng-view></div>
```

This is what I want, and is not working

JavaScript

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/home', {
                    controller:'myCtrl'
                })
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        }
    ])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){})

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule'])
```

HTML

```
hello!
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Trying to use this for multipage app, without declaring ng-app and ng-controller in every single page.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do it seems conflicting with the concept of [Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)

However what you want to do is possible in a different way, the [Deep Linking](http://docs.angularjs.org/cookbook/deeplinking) cookbook example may help shed some light for you:

http://docs.angularjs.org/cookbook/deeplinking